# I'm trying to take a SEAM 2.3 project and deploy it on Jboss-WildFly 8.x

Tags: java, jboss, seam, wildfly

Hello All Please help,

I've tried everything.  I'm trying to deploy a Seam project on WildFly Jboss new server.  I'm getting errors tho.  I put the ear file in WildFly-8.2.0Final then create a ear.dodeploy file and wait for it to automatically run it.  The Services with missing/unavailable dependencies is the error I need to get around.  I get this following error:

```
15:46:12,061 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS014613: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "Atlast2.3.ear")]) - failure description: {"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
    "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.\"Atlast2.3\".jboss-seam.TimerServiceDispatcher.ValidatorFactory is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.\"Atlast2.3\".jboss-seam.TimerServiceDispatcher]",
    "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.\"Atlast2.3\".jboss-seam.TimerServiceDispatcher.Validator is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.\"Atlast2.3\".jboss-seam.TimerServiceDispatcher]",
    "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.\"Atlast2.3\".jboss-seam.EjbSynchronizations.Validator is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.\"Atlast2.3\".jboss-seam.EjbSynchronizations]",
    "jboss.persistenceunit.\"Atlast2.3.ear/Atlast2.3.jar#Atlast2.3\".__FIRST_PHASE__ is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.\"Atlast2.3Datasource\"]",
    "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.\"Atlast2.3\".jboss-seam.EjbSynchronizations.InAppClientContainer is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.\"Atlast2.3\".jboss-seam.EjbSynchronizations]",
    "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.\"Atlast2.3\".jboss-seam.EjbSynchronizations.InstanceName is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.\"Atlast2.3\".jboss-seam.EjbSynchronizations]",
    "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.\"Atlast2.3\".jboss-seam.EjbSynchronizations.ValidatorFactory is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.\"Atlast2.3\".jboss-seam.EjbSynchronizations]",
    "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.\"Atlast2.3\".jboss-seam.TimerServiceDispatcher.InstanceName is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.\"Atlast2.3\".jboss-seam.TimerServiceDispatcher]",
    "jboss.naming.context.java.comp.\"Atlast2.3\".jboss-seam.TimerServiceDispatcher.InAppClientContainer is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.\"Atlast2.3\".jboss-seam.TimerServiceDispatcher]"
]}
15:46:12,301 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS018559: Deployed "Atlast2.3.ear" (runtime-name : "Atlast2.3.ear")
15:46:12,302 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014776:    Newly corrected services:
      service jboss.naming.context.java.module."Atlast2.3"."Atlast2.3.war" (new available)
      service jboss.naming.context.java.module."Atlast2.3".jboss-seam (new available)
      service jboss.persistenceunit."Atlast2.3.ear/Atlast2.3.jar#Atlast2.3".__FIRST_PHASE__ (new available)
```

Comment: which version of Seam? you will find it easier to deploy to JBoss AS7 (EAP 6), a lot of the seam libs will not work with wildfly (seam is based around Java EE5 and Wildfly EE7

Comment: I'm working with SEAM 2.3.1.  Yes I actually had the Application running on a JBoss server before but we are migrating over to WildFly8.  I have tried and still am trying, getting errors tho.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks @DaveB

Comment: Ok, I tried deploying a SEAM 2.3.1 app to Wildfly recently and came across similar errors, gave up as the official advice is 'its not been tested for this', I have seen some reports of people doing it, I guess it depends which libs you are using in your app...sorry I cant be more help

Comment: Ok thanks and hope to hear back from you soon.  It looks like I almost got it running.  I'm getting a java.lang.IllegalStateException when I try to run the application.  I took out the weld.  The exception looks like this ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-3) UT005023: Exception handling request to /Atlas3/home.seam: java.lang.IllegalStateException
 at com.sun.faces.context.FacesContextImpl.assert...  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When migrating a Seam 2.3 EAR application to WildFly 9, I was able to resolve the `WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies`
 error analogous to the one above by deploying the Seam JAR *after* the EJB JAR. This can be configured in the EAR `META-INF/application.xml`:

```
<application xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" version="6">
  <initialize-in-order>true</initialize-in-order>
  <module>
    <ejb>myapp-ejb.jar</ejb>
  </module>
  <module>
    <ejb>jboss-seam-2.3.1.Final.jar</ejb>
  </module>
  ...
</application>
```

It may be sufficent to set `initialize-in-order` to `false`, but I need this option set to `true` because there are multiple WARs in this EAR.

The `java.lang.IllegalStateException` was solved in my case by installing and activating JSF 2.1 instead of JSF 2.2 bundled with WildFly. This is explained [here](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/Seam23OnWildfly89) and [here](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/StepsToAddAnyNewJSFImplementationOrVersionToWildFly) in detail; it boils down to these steps:

```
git clone git://github.com/wildfly/wildfly.git
cd wildfly
git checkout 9.0.1.Final
./build.sh
cd jsf/multi-jsf-installer
mvn -Djsf-version=2.1.29 -Pmojarra-2.x clean assembly:single
mv target/install-mojarra-2.1.29.zip target/install-mojarra-2.1.29.cli
[Start WildFly in another console: bin/standalone.sh]
bin/jboss-cli.sh -c "deploy target/install-mojarra-2.1.29.cli"
```

Restart WildFly and verify that the new version appears:

```
bin/jboss-cli.sh -c --commands="/subsystem=jsf/:list-active-jsf-impls"
```

To ensure that the correct version is used, both of the following changes were necessary in my case:

In the EAR `META-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml`:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.0">
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="javax.faces.api" export="true" slot="mojarra-2.1.29" />
            <module name="com.sun.jsf-impl" export="true" slot="mojarra-2.1.29" />
            <module name="org.jboss.as.jsf-injection" export="true" slot="mojarra-2.1.29" />
            ...
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

In the WAR `WEB-INF/web.xml`:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.jboss.jbossfaces.JSF_CONFIG_NAME</param-name>
    <param-value>mojarra-2.1.29</param-value>
</context-param>
```